# My HTML + CSS drop-down menu does not appear when hovering

Tags: html, css, debugging

```css
/* FONTS */
@font-face {
    font-family:'MontserratNormal';
    src:url(../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg#MontserratNormal) format("svg");
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'MontserratBlack';
    src:url(../fonts/montserrat-black-webfont.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/montserrat-black-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/montserrat-black-webfont.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/montserrat-black-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/montserrat-black-webfont.svg#MontserratBlack) format("svg");
    font-weight:900;
    font-style:normal
}

@font-face {
    font-family:'MontserratBold';
    src:url(../fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/montserrat-bold-webfont.svg#MontserratBold) format("svg");
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:normal
}

@font-face {
    font-family:"ParentsSuckRegular";
    src:url(../fonts/parentssuck.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/parentssuck.eot#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(../fonts/parentssuck.woff) format("woff"),url(../fonts/parentssuck.ttf) format("truetype"),url(../fonts/parentssuck.svg) format("svg");
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:normal
}

/* HEADER */
#logo {
    float:left
}

.mainHeader {
    clear:both;
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px
}

.mainNav {
    margin:0
}

.mainNav li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:50px;
    font-family:MontserratBlack;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:35px;
    color:#BBB;
    position:static;
    line-height:1.9em
}

#about,#training,#news,#contact,a {
    color:#bcbcbc
}

#about:hover,#training:hover,#news:hover,#contact:hover,nav li .current {
    color:#13C63E
}

a {
    text-decoration:none
}

/* DROP-DOWN MENUS */
.dropdown {
    position:relative
}

.drop-nav {
    position:absolute;
    display:none
}

.drop-nav li {
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2)
}

.dropdown:hover > .drop-nav {
    display:block
}

.dropdown1 {
    position:relative
}

.drop-nav1 {
    position:absolute;
    display:none
}

.drop-nav1 li {
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2)
}

.dropdown1:hover > .drop-nav1 {
    display:block
}
```

```html
    <header class="mainHeader">
        <ul class="mainNav">
            <li>
                <a class="current" href="/" id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
            </li>


            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="/about" id="about">About</a>

                <ul class="drop-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/testimonials">Testimonials</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li id="news">Services</li>


            <li class="dropdown1">
                <ul class="drop-nav1">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/the-meltdown-bootcamp" id="bootcamp">The Meltdown</a>
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="/personal-training" id="personalTraining">Personal Training</a>
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="/PIYO" id="piyo">PIYO / Burn!</a>
                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="/LBDProject" id="bootcamp">Little Black Dress</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/training" id="training">Blog</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/contact" id="contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

I'm having a bit of trouble with a drop-down menu in my code. I made one based on [this.](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-simple-css-dropdown-menu) As you can see, the second drop-down menu does not drop. Sorry if this is a simple issue, I started learning HTML and CSS two days ago.
Thanks!

Comment: Please reduce your code and create a *minimal* working example. Dumping all your code makes it difficult to sift through your code and diagnose the issue at times.

Comment: I second that ^. When reproducing the issue you don't need to include everything, like the fonts and such are completely unnecessary to fix your issue. Criticism aside, welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working for you http://jsfiddle.net/b64n0wdn/

Your html was a little bit out of wack, no big deal it happens to the best of us :)

In the you have the first drop down like:

```
 <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="/about" id="about">About</a>

            <ul class="drop-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="/testimonials">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

In order to make it work I had to put "services" in an anchor uniformly like that previous dropdown, like so:

```
 <li class="dropdown1">
            <a href="/services" id="news">Services</a>
            <ul class="drop-nav1">
                <li>
                    <a href="/the-meltdown-bootcamp" id="bootcamp">The     Meltdown</a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a href="/personal-training" id="personalTraining">Personal Training</a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a href="/PIYO" id="piyo">PIYO / Burn!</a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a href="/LBDProject" id="bootcamp">Little Black Dress</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```